# Limit sets of representations of once-punctured torus groups and circle packings

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\rho\colon\pi_1(T_1)\to PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ be a faithful representation of the fundamental group of a once-punctured torus. If both the components of the convex core in the quotient manifold are three-times punctured spheres, then the limit set is made of an infinite union of circles which satisfy certain properties.
Do you know where it is possible to find a nice description of this?
I found this fact on a paper, but the references seem to be circular, and each one sends to a different paper which in turn sends to other ones, or to some mysterious preprint which I was not able to find. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 4):

You could have a look at [Indra's Pearls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_Pearls_%28book%29).